# Compile error trying to use Grails' Quartz plugin

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to install and use Grails' [Quartz plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/quartz). My grails' version is 2.3.7

I added `compile ":quartz:1.0.1"` to my Build.config;
and downloaded `quartz-2.2.1.jar` and `quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar`; and then added these `.jar` files to my `/lib` folder.

When I try `grails run-app`, the following error appears:

```
Compile error during compilation with javac.
C:\Users\username\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Siscoserv-web\target\work\plugins\quartz-1.0-RC11\src\java\grails\plugins\quartz\CustomTriggerFactoryBean.java:51: error: inconvertible types
        if(customTrigger instanceof AbstractTrigger){
           ^
  required: AbstractTrigger
  found:    Trigger
C:\Users\username\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Siscoserv-web\target\work\plugins\quartz-1.0-RC11\src\java\grails\plugins\quartz\CustomTriggerFactoryBean.java:52: error: inconvertible types
            AbstractTrigger at =(AbstractTrigger) customTrigger;
                                                  ^
  required: AbstractTrigger
  found:    Trigger
C:\Users\username\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Siscoserv-web\target\work\plugins\quartz-1.0-RC11\src\java\grails\plugins\quartz\CustomTriggerFactoryBean.java:56: error: no suitable method found for setJobKey(Key)
                at.setJobKey(jobDetail.getKey());
                  ^
    method AbstractTrigger.setJobKey(JobKey) is not applicable
      (actual argument Key cannot be converted to JobKey by method invocation conversion)
    method MutableTrigger.setJobKey(JobKey) is not applicable
      (actual argument Key cannot be converted to JobKey by method invocation conversion)
```

When I tried to install the plugin and run Grails, the following error appeared during `run-app`:

```
|Compiling 216 source files
.Error 
|
Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:61)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy:68)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:60)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:57)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:44)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure8.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:42)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure8.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:41)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
Error |
Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

I didn't erase the class's name in the error above, it just doesn't appear.

Comment: Why did you put those JARs in your lib directory? The plugin should contain all the needed dependencies. You are likely creating a conflict.

Comment: I put the JARs there because it didn't work the normal way

Comment: What didn't work the normal way? Did you issue a grails clean and grails refresh-dependencies?

Comment: I updated the question with the error that appeared using the normal way of installing plugins. I didn't try to clean the application because I tried the normal way at first. I tried to clean and refresh dependencies right now and got the same error (`IncompatibleClassChangeError`). And no, right now there are no `.jar` files in the /lib folder. The plugin didn't give any warnings/errors during installation. The errors only happen during Grails' compilation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what the problem was:
It seems shiro has quartz as a dependency, and it was downloading a different version than the one the quartz plugin uses.

I fixed it adding the following `excludes` statement to my `Build.config`.

```
compile (":shiro:1.2.0") {
            excludes([name: 'quartz', group: 'org.opensymphony.quartz'])
}
```

I found out the problem by creating a new project and enabling the quartz plugin, and then the others using some kind of binary search, until I found the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the plugin as

```
compile ":quartz:1.0.1"
```

version `1.0.1`, then why are you getting errors from `quartz-1.0-RC11`. From stacktrace:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Siscoserv-web\target\work\plugins\
quartz-1.0-RC11\src\java\grails\plugins\quartz\CustomTriggerFactoryBean.java:51: 
error: inconvertible types
```

Delete the `traget` directory, delete the old version of quartz from local `.m2` (local maven repo), delete other reference (like in `.grails\app\..`), if any, from the app and then run `grails clean && grails compile`, it should be good.

I do not see any problem with the plugin getting compiled with a grails app built on 2.3.7.

Comment: Local maven repository. Usually found in `C:\Users\username\.m2\repository`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the JAR files from your lib directory. You do not need them there. The plugin will provide all the required JARs. This is one of the benefits of the plugin system for Grails. Adding these JARs to your lib directory is causing conflicts.